# How to efficiently convert combination value to category based on each value?

Tags: r

I have a vector like this: 1=cat, 2=dog,3=duck,4=chicken, 5=donkey

```
animal_type<-c("1", "1 2","1 2 3","1 2 3 4", "1 2 3 4 5", "1 2 3 5","1 2 4","1 2 4 5","1 2 5","1 3")
```

Now, instead of this combination value, I want to convert them in to category based on each animal type, which ideally looks like (the number in column "count" is just made up, not the correct number based on the dataset):

```
     animal_type  count
        cat        3
        dog        6
        duck       7
        chicken    4
        donkey     3
```

or instead of animal's name, just like this:

```
    animal_type  count
      1            3     
      2            6
      3            7
      4            4
      5            3
```

My question is whether there is an efficient way to achieve this goal in R ? Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: Are those 'count' values correct i.e. based on the example you showed.

Comment: @akrun, no, they are just random number I made up....the original dataset does not have that vector, i think I can use number instead of animal's name, and then change them to name later if needs. I just don't know how to get the result like second table shows...

Comment: your input example with `id` was kind of not giving the expected output

Comment: Thanks a lot, @akrun, I ran the code you provided below, and that is exactly what I expect for output. Actually I realized that I do not need  "id" column. It should be simplified as a vector conversion question but not dataframe...LOL. Thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `separate_rows` to split the column, then use the index to change the values to animal names and do a group by summarise or use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(animal_type, convert = TRUE)  %>% 
  group_by(id, animal_type = c('cat', 'dog', 'duck', 'chicken', 'donkey')[animal_type]) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```